# Function on specific key in nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I apply the multiply function on all values with the key colorScheme in the below nested object? Thus, returning the same array with the colorScheme changed from 10 --> 20? The object has a variable length for each rep.

```js
function multiply(el) {
  return el * 2
}

var array = {
    "rep1": {
      "type": [
        "cartoon"
      ],
      "colorScheme": [10]
    },
    {
      "rep2": {
        "type": [
          "cartoon"
        ],
        "colorScheme": [10]
      },
      "rep3": {
        "type": [
          "cartoon"
        ],
        "color": [
          "green"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: is this a complete object or will it have `rep3` , `rep4` etc .. as well ?

Comment: There's only 1 `colorScheme` property in your object, so `multiply(array.rep1.colorScheme[0])` will work. If you have more properties than that which need the logic performed on, please add a more representative example to the question. I would also strongly suggest you use an array for this instead of incrementally named properties in an object

Comment: @ShyamPillai No it is not complete and each rep3 can have a variety of keys.

Comment: Your `array` variable, is an object, and to know how to update it we will need to know the possible structures it may have.

Comment: Thanks for editing, however the data structure you've shown is invalid. Is it possible for the solution to change the structure to an array?

Comment: Sure, but will `colorScheme` always be nested at the root level of every `repN` object ? Also, calling an object `array` is quite misleading..

Answer (score 2):

You will need to be a bit creative with `reduce`, `map` and the spread (`...`) operator.

```js
function multiply(el) {
  return el * 2
}

var array = {
      "rep1": {
        "type": [
          "cartoon"
        ],
        "colorScheme": [10]
    },
    
      "rep2": {
        "type": [
          "cartoon"
        ],
        "colorScheme": [10]
      },
      "rep3": {
        "type": [
          "cartoon"
        ],
        "color": [
          "green"
        ]
      }
    }
    
var result = Object.entries(array).reduce( (acc, [key, value]) => {
   if(value.colorScheme)
    acc[key] = {...value, colorScheme: value.colorScheme.map(multiply)};
   else
    acc[key] = {...value};
  return acc;
},{})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```js
function multiply(el){
  return el * 2
}

const nestedObject = {
"rep1": {
  "type": [
      "cartoon"
    ],
    "colorScheme": [10]
},
"rep2": {
   "type": [
      "cartoon"
   ],
   "colorScheme": [10]
},
"rep3": {
   "type": [
      "cartoon"
   ],
   "color": [
      "green"
   ]
}
}
for (const key of Object.keys(nestedObject)){
if(nestedObject[key].colorScheme) 
    nestedObject[key].colorScheme = nestedObject[key].colorScheme.map(multiply)
}
console.log(nestedObject)
```

Comment: you're assuming that `colorScheme` always exists ?

Comment: no... and what is else the matter? is this not working as expected?

Comment: @ShyamPillai No sometimes it does not exist et all.

Comment: Yup it's better now. This should work right @Nivel ?